# Unexpected token in expression or statement (Trying to set new domain to aliases)

Tags: powershell, email, exchange-server

I've run into an issue while trying to add a new domain to user aliases on our exchange server. I ran:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri “https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/” -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

Import-PSSession $session

$Mailboxes = Get-Mailbox

Foreach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes) {$NewAddress = $Mailbox.Alias + "@newdomain.com" $Mailbox.EmailAddresses += $NewAddress Set-Mailbox -Identity $Mailbox.Alias -EmailAddresses $Mailbox.EmailAddresses}
```

After running the 4th line, I run into:

```
$Mailbox.EmailAddresses += $NewAddress Set-Mailbox -Identity $Mai ...
+                    ~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '$Mailbox' in expression or statement.
```

As well as:

```
At line:1 char:128
+ ... += $NewAddress Set-Mailbox -Identity $Mailbox.Alias -EmailAddresses $Mailbox.Ema ...
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'Set-Mailbox' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

I can't seem to figure out why $Mailbox and Set-Mailbox aren't working in this scenario. This is the first time I'm attempting something like this via PowerShell so I'm a little lost.

Any insight would be wonderful.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to issue each command on a separate line. The error you're getting means that PowerShell is attempting to pass `$Mailbox` and `Set-Mailbox` as arguments to `$NewAddress =` instead of running them as separate commands

```
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri “https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/” -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

Import-PSSession $session

$Mailboxes = Get-Mailbox

Foreach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes) 
{
    $NewAddress = $Mailbox.Alias + "@newdomain.com"
    $Mailbox.EmailAddresses += $NewAddress
    Set-Mailbox -Identity $Mailbox.Alias -EmailAddresses $Mailbox.EmailAddresses
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually works for me, however I wouldn't recommend this approach.  You should use the full capabilities of `Set-Mailbox`. The `-EmailAddresses` parameter will take a hash that allows you to define adds and removes. In your case this looks like:

```
Foreach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes) 
{
    $NewAddress = $Mailbox.Alias + "@newdomain.com"
    Set-Mailbox -Identity $Mailbox.Alias -EmailAddresses @{ Add = $NewAddress }
}
```

In general steer clear of `+=`. If you are operating on a large number of objects it can be very slow. There are several reasons for this, but mostly because arrays are immutable, so `+=` causes a recreate and copy every time you use it.  This obviously has a compound effect the more you use it.  It's a bigger problem if the array keeps getting bigger however with your original code the number of time you invoke it could be an issue too.  There's a lot of information about this on the internet.  If I have time I'll post some commentary from other StackOverflow discussions.

At any rate, you don't need to directly append an array in your case.  Let me know if that helps.